# Regex matching className in jsx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text file, from which I want to extract `className` attribute.

```
<div className={classes} {...attributes} onClick={ev => toggleAccordion(ev.target)}>
   {content ? (<h3 className="no-margin text-medium main-heading text-heading" style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}}>
   {content}
```

**Objectives:**

1. match `className="no-margin text-medium main-heading text-heading"` - (Passed)
2. match `className={classes}` - (Failed)

**Regex and results which I have tried:**

1. `className\s*=\s*["\{]` matches both `className="` or `className={`
2. `className\s*=\s*["\{].+` matches both `className={classes} {...attributes} onClick={ev => toggleAccordion(ev.target)}>` and `className="no-margin text-medium main-heading text-heading" style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}}>`
3. `className\s*=\s*["\{].+"` matches `className="no-margin text-medium main-heading text-heading"` **(one of the objective)**
4. `className\s*=\s*["\{].+\}` matches `className={classes} {...attributes} onClick={ev => toggleAccordion(ev.target)}` and `className="no-margin text-medium main-heading text-heading" style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}}`

All are using the global `/g` flag.

Comment: /className="([\s\w-]+)"/

Comment: It has the same result. Only objective 1 is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this :  `className\s*=\s*[\"{]([^\"}]*)?[\"}]`

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqnIiq/18) here